# I have second Model I am trying to fill in a View and return. MVC 5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, data-annotations, models

I start in the controller

```
ViewBag.EmailStuff = new EmailStuff();
```

Then in the View, I try to get this model because the View is based on a different one.

```
 @{var es = ViewBag.EmailStuff as EmailStuff;}


@using (Html.BeginForm("ContactStore", "Store", FormMethod.Post, new {emailstuff=es))
```

and I have the Validaton working for these 2 fields, it fires if they are empty

```
@Html.EditorFor(m => es.EventName)
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => es.EventName, "", new { @class = "text-danger-yellow" })
<br />

@Html.EditorFor(m => es.MessageBody)
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => es.MessageBody, "", new { @class = "text-danger-yellow" })
```

But I can't figure out how to get the values to the controller if the fields have info in them.

At the controller, the model I am referencing returns nulls for both inputs even though DataAnnotations works.

I know this is a hack. I'm trying to get away from the Forms collection and learn how to use Models.
The view itself is using a different model than the one I am trying to validate.
At the top of view you can see a different model that has nothing to do with the 2 fields I am sending to an emailer.

```
@model Stores.Models.vProfiles
@using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity
@using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework
@using Stores.Models
```

Here is where the info is supposed to be coming in:

```
public ActionResult ContactStore(EmailStuff emailstuff)
{
```

Here is my model:

```
    public class EmailStuff
    {
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Enter an event name")]
        public string EventName { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "You need to enter a message")]
        public string MessageBody { get; set; }


    }
}
```

I'll probably be burned in hell for all this spaghetti, but I'm hoping there is an easy solution that I am missing (besides glueing several views together).

Comment: Create a view model containing the properties you need. Do not use `ViewBag`. Your creating inputs with name attributes that have no relationship to you model so cannot bind to your model. Alternatively use `@Html.Action()` to call a server method that returns a partial view of your form

Comment: In you form you're saying that your POST actions is ContactShuttle (in the Shuttles controller). In the controller that you showed we see that the Action is called ContactStore.

Comment: sorry ssimeonov. I was using some code I found somewhere to start with.

Comment: Thanks Stephen. Sigh. I was hoping to avoid this because the View is based on a big Model, vProfiles. But you are right. The good news I'm thinking is that the big model is display only, no edit inputs.

Comment: @JustJohn, Then create a partial with `@model EmailStuff` and create a form based on it, then in the main view use `@Html.Action()` to call a controller method that return that partial view.

Answer (score 0):

Just like @Stephen said return same model to the view like;

```
var emailStuff = new EmailStuff();
emailStuff = ViewBag.EmailStuff;
return View(emailStuff);
```

and in the view use like this.

```
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.EventName)
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.EventName, "", new { @class = "text-danger-yellow" })
```

after that you should be getting the data you want at controller side when you post the form.

Comment: Yes, Qsprec, that looks good for the View that is based on EmailStuff, but if you look in my question, I have another Model the View is based on.

Comment: You can create a new model that contains these two model and pass that model to the view. Have you tried this?

Comment: Yes. Currently pulling my hair out because only one of the models is coming back with data. The other is for DisplayFor helpers, but I need it's ID coming back. But, it comes back null.

Answer (score 0):

So I made a big model to hold the 2 models.

```
public class MainPageModel
    {
    public Model1 Model1
        { get; set; }
    public Model2 Model2
        { get; set; }
    }
```

Then I filled one of them in the ActionResult that opened the View. (the other one was to collect an email subject and messagebody.)

```
Model.Model1 = context.myTable(where whatever = id)
```

And sent the big model to the View

```
return View(Model)
```

In the View I declared the big model at the top

```
@model myAppName.Models.Model
```

and filled a bunch of @Html.DisplayFor(m=>m.Model.Model1) (notice how I referenced the sub model. . . I'm learning!)

The other model was used to get an email messagebody using

```
@TextAreaFor (m=>m.Model.Model2)
```

Now, on the Form Submit, the big model went to the ActionResult I wanted, but
the Model.Model1 was null! go figure. I had to put the Model.Model1.AccountID into a @Html.HiddenFor
before anything would be returned to the Controller.

Why? Well, after pulling out half my hair someone at work told me that you can't pass a Model without editing it in an @Html.EditorFor or @Html.HiddenFor. . . . @Html.DisplayFor wouldn't do the job
. . . .so, I went with a @Html.Hiddenfor to get my AccountID back in to the controller. I could see the model was it was coming in, but it was null until I used the HiddenFor.

You learn something new everyday. Too bad I spent 8 hours trying to figure this out. I appreciate everyone's help.

I hope this helps someone besides myself. And thank you everyone.